# How to get the label of radio button using selenium?

Tags: testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to fetch associate value of radio button.The HTML code is like

```
    <td>
<input id="ctl00_mainContent_rdbList_0" type="radio" checked="checked" value="1" name="ctl00$mainContent$rdbList"/>
<label for="ctl00_mainContent_rdbList_0">Employment History</label>
</td>
```

i am provideing the xpath of radio button that is .//*[@id='ctl00_mainContent_rdbList_0']

and want to fetch the value **Employment History**

please help me to find out the best solution with selenium web driver 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to use xpath and walk through the nodes. After finding the intended radio you can walk to the parent and simply point to the label

```
//input[@id='ctl00_mainContent_rdbList_0']/../label
```

Or, in this case you have the for attribute in label tag that can also be used to find the label for the same radio.

A cssSelector would be easier for that

```
[for='ctl00_mainContent_rdbList_0']
```

Comment: is this
string text = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xPathVal)).text;

please confirm.

Comment: Are you using Java? if so then `getText()` for C# `Text`

Comment: Thanks a lot .I am using C# .Let me try